# Issue while installing Tensorflow via Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~-mpy\\core\\multiarray.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Although when I tried `python -m pip install tensorflow` in command prompt it installed the packagen, when I am trying to import Keras in Jupyter notebook I am getting above error.

Comment: You need to run it as the administrator ```runas python -m pip install tensorflow```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on Windows. Open your command prompt as administrator and then type `python -m pip install tensorflow --user`. Let me know if this fixed your issue.